# Maven multiple repositories - jcenter, nexus

Tags: maven, nexus, bintray, jcenter

I am trying to set up maven with 2 repositories - jcenter & nexus. From nexus, we don't have the ability to proxy to jcenter. Hence I need a set up which can do the following-

- If a artifact is found in nexus, download it.
- If not found, go to jcenter to download artifact.

With the below settings.xml, it seems like maven only tries to download from central (which is set to bintray here, because its a super set of maven central). How can I tell maven to look in central and nexus?

Note- I have tried  `<mirrorOf>central, !nexus</mirrorOf>`

```
 <mirrors>
   <mirror>
      <id>bintray</id>
      <name>bintray</name>
      <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
    <mirror>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>!bintray, *</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://some/url/goes/here</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>allow-snapshots</id>
      <activation><activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault></activation>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Comment: Please have a look at if that help http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html

Comment: Thank you, I had already visited the website and updated my settings.xml, but didnt work for me.

Comment: "<mirrorOf>!bintray,*</mirrorOf>" will work, provided that you have a repository definition with ID of "bintray" in your settings.xml file. Not sure about that leading space you have in front of the asterisk though, it might be problem?

Comment: rseddon, thanks, I didnt realize that the space could be problem. Ill check it out and let you know if I have luck.

Comment: Here is my repository settings and I corrected the space with no luck. Do you see anything with settings that needs to be corrected?

`<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>allow-snapshots</id>
      <activation><activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault></activation>
      <repositories>
     <repository>
            <id>bintray</id>
            <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
   <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
   <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by specifying multiple repo's in my parent pom. multiple repos in settings.xml had no effect on maven.